# How to run autoclick on first button in button set in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have set of buttons, I used ng-repeat. I would like to have pressed first button after load page

I thought about ng-init but I don't know how to use reference to first button..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$first` to return a boolean that is true if the element is the first in the array, and then put some logic in there that will check for that along the lines of

```
if($first){
 //do something
}
```

or something like

```
ng-class="$first ? conditionA : conditionB"
```

if you want to conditionally set CSS

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: `<td ng-repeat="item in items"><a href=""><button type="button">{{item.titile}}</button></a></td>`
- I need to have clicked first button after load page

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need with `ng-init` like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a href="">
        <button type="button" ng-click="onClick($index)" ng-init="$first && onClick($index)">{{item.title}}</button>
    </a>
</td>
```

`onClick` function will be called only for the first button

see working demo here: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwn8keac/10/)

Comment: Thank you for your aswer, I no need alert, need to have clicked button, button should to have 'selected mark' after action.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'selected mark'? You don't have a function for button click? You need a css class?

Comment: so you only want a border around the first button, without any action?